# Select Distinct Records for min date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have a query where In I need to select all the distinct ID's from the table, also need to select only the min(date) so that I get records that were inserted 1st and not ID's for all dates.

Basically this is what I am looking for -

Table 1 ||     Table 2-
ID ||           ID Date

1  ||  1   11/11/2010
1  ||  1 10/11/2010
3  ||  3  12/01/2010
4  ||  4  01/01/2010
4  ||  4  02/01/2010

So i need to get all records from Table 2(table1.ID=table2.ID) which has the Minimum Date along with that ID

Result here would be
1  10/11/2010
3  12/01/2010
4  01/01/2010

Here is my query

```
select u.firstName,u.lastName ,count(*) as theCount
from tbl_appts_change_log c,tbl_appts a, tbl_users u
where  c.appt_id=a.ID
and c.user_id=u.userID
 and c.appt_id in ( select  c.appt_id,min(c.date) from tbl_appts_change_log c, tbl_appts a
                        where  c.appt_id=a.ID
                        and a.satellite_id='160' GROUP BY c.appt_id)    
group by u.firstName,u.lastName
 order by count(*) desc,u.firstName,u.lastName
```

Comment: Could you post your schema?  I don't understand what you are trying to do with this query....

Comment: I was not able to use aggregate function and a second column for the subquery..it was giving all sorts of errors....

Comment: @Santosh, try to rewrite what you exactly need in plain english without using SQL keywords such as distinct and min

Comment: I have re-written what I was looking for..hope that helps...also I found the solution, look at Leslie's solution as I used that...

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
select u.firstName,u.lastName ,count(*) as theCount
from tbl_appts_change_log c
INNER JOIN tbl_appts a on c.appt_id=a.ID
INNER JOIN tbl_users u on c.user_id=u.userID
INNER JOIN ( select  c.appt_id,min(c.date) as LastDate 
    from tbl_appts_change_log c 
    INNER JOIN  tbl_appts a on  c.appt_id=a.ID
    Where a.satellite_id='160' GROUP BY c.appt_id) d
on c.appt_id = d.appt_id and c.date = d.LastDate
group by u.firstName,u.lastName
order by count(*) desc,u.firstName,u.lastName
```

Comment: hi leslie..thanks for that SQL...it works fine...I had tried the Group by but did not try the next part of it !!!

Comment: great!  you should accept it as the answer then!  Glad to have been able to help!

Answer (score 1):

I am ignoring your code as it seems to be a completely different scenario from what you have described in your question i.e Table1 and Table2. If all you want is the minimum date for each ID all you need is

```
SELECT T1.ID,   MIN(T2.Date)
FROM Table1 T1
    JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

But i am guessing what you really wanted was something like this?

```
Table 1 || Table 2-
ID || ID Date Desc

1 || 1 11/11/2010 AAA
1 || 1 10/11/2010 BBB
3 || 3 12/01/2010 CCC
4 || 4 01/01/2010 DDD
4 || 4 02/01/2010 EEE
```

And the expected result

```
1 10/11/2010 BBB
3 12/01/2010 CCC
4 01/01/2010 DDD
```

This is slightly more complicated than just doing a group by, and there are two ways to solve it. You could try both and see which one performs best

Method 1 : Using Row number

```
;WITH ResultCTE AS
(
    SELECT T2.ID, T2.Date, T2.Desc,
       RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T2.ID ORDER BY T2.Date ASC)   
    FROM Table1 T1
          JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
)    
SELECT ID, Date, Desc
FROM ResultCTE    
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Method 2: Nested query

```
;WITH ResultCTE AS
(
    SELECT T2.ID, MIN(T2.Date) AS Date
    FROM Table1 T1
        JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    GROUP BY T2.ID
)
SELECT T.ID, T.Date, T.Desc
FROM Table2 T
    JOIN ResultCTE R
        ON R.ID = T.ID AND R.Date = T.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.firstName,
  u.lastName ,
  COUNT(*) AS theCount
FROM tbl_appts_change_log c,
  tbl_appts a,
  tbl_users u
WHERE c.appt_id=a.ID
AND c.user_id  =u.userID
AND a.satellite_id = '160'
AND c.date = (SELECT MIN(ci.date)
  FROM tbl_appts_change_log ci,
    tbl_appts ai
  WHERE ci.appt_id   = ai.ID
  AND ci.appt_id = c.appt_id
  AND ai.satellite_id= a.satellite_id
  )
GROUP BY u.firstName,
  u.lastName
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC,
  u.firstName,
  u.lastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.firstName,u.lastName,count(*) as theCount,cm.MinDate
from ( 
    select c.appt_id,min(c.date) as MinDate
    from tbl_appts_change_log c, tbl_appts a 
    where c.appt_id=a.ID 
        and a.satellite_id='160' 
    GROUP BY c.appt_id
    ) cm 
inner join tbl_appts_change_log c on cm.appt_id = c.appt_id and cm.MinDate = c.date 
inner join tbl_appts a on c.appt_id=a.ID 
inner join tbl_users u on c.user_id=u.userID 
group by u.firstName,u.lastName 
order by count(*) desc,u.firstName,u.lastName
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is-

Table 1 ||     Table 2-
ID ||           ID Date

1  ||  1   11/11/2010
1  ||  1 10/11/2010
3  ||  3  12/01/2010
4  ||  4  01/01/2010
4  ||  4  02/01/2010

Try using this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i1.id, i2.dt
FROM Table1 i1 JOIN (SELECT id, min(date) dt FROM Table2 GROUP BY id) i2
ON i1.id=i2.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're after?

```
select u.firstName,u.lastName ,count(*) as theCount
from tbl_appts_change_log c,tbl_appts a, tbl_users u
where  c.appt_id=a.ID
and c.user_id=u.userID
and a.satellite_id = '160'
and c.date = (
  select min(date) 
  from tbl_appts_change_log c, tbl_appts a
  where c.appt_id = a.id
  and a.satellite_id = '160'
)
group by u.firstName,u.lastName
order by count(*) desc,u.firstName,u.lastName
```

Comment: i need to select ID's for the min date